# How can you override the argspec of a python function, e.g. to make the result of the help() function more useful?

Tags: python, built-in

I have a python function that only takes in keyword arguments:

```
def my_func(**kwargs):
```

I am splitting the keyword arguments among two separate functions, which have their keyword arguments defined explicitly:

```
def my_subfunc_1(a=None,b=None):
def my_subfunc_2(c=None,d=None):
```

When I issue `help(my_func)` I only get the description for `my_func(**kwargs)`. However, ideally I would like the result of this to be `my_func(a=None,b=None,c=None,d=None)`.

I can fetch the arguments of `my_subfunc_1` and `my_subfunc_2` with `inspect.getfullargspec()`. However, I am not sure how to use this information to override the part of `my_func` that the `help()` function reads from to fetch the displayed `**kwargs`.

Answer (score 0):

You can override it by using `inspect`:

```
args_ = []
for param in inspect.signature(f).parameters.values():
    if param.name not in [p.name for p in args_]+['self','cls', 'args', 'kwargs']: args_.append(param)
wrapper.__signature__ = inspect.Signature(parameters=args_)
```